# Force reload of data for excel report

Tags: java, ajax, excel, jsp, displaytag

I use displaytag to show data in a table with an excel report. Every row has an checkbox that when clicked changes a flag in the database for that row. This is handled by Ajax. So when I select/unselect the checkbox Ajax updates a column in the database and the checkbox state is preserved in the html.

The problem is that when I change a state of couple of checkboxes the changes are not reflected in the excel report because it seems to use the data which have been uploaded at the beginning.

The question is:

Is it possible to force reload of data from the database for the excel report to have the fresh data in the report?

Answer (score 0):

XLLoop will help you.
This is an open source framework for implementing Excel user-defined functions (UDFs) on a centralised server (a function server). 
Please see the details [here.](http://xlloop.sourceforge.net/)

**It has the following features:**

Extensible Java server framework.
Native server frameworks written in many other languages (see languages section).
Popup for long running operations (with option to cancel)
Support for hosting C++ XLLs via JXLL.
Reflection-based function adaptor for extremely quick deployment of java methods.
Bean scripting framework adaptor so functions can be written in any BSF-supported language (eg. Ruby, Python, Javascript).
Lisp Function Handler for evaluating Lisp expressions on the fly.
Functions can be dynamically added to Excel without restart.
Functions can be registered as Excel functions (with help information).
Fast binary protocol with multiple-server fail-over/scalability.
JSON over HTTP(S) protocol.
NEW: Can be configured to connect to multiple function servers (providers).